# Default selection of header and item checkboxes in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have gridview with header and item checkboxes.when i select header checkbox my code able to select all item checkboxes.when i un select header checkbox my code able to un select all item checkboxes.

Here my issue is when my page is loading(means when grid is loading first time) by default the header and item checkboxes should be selected.how can we do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) Event in Gridview

```
protected void GridViewName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row .RowType == DataControlRowType .DataRow )
        {
             //Your Code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In grid view columns write like this

```
<Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkhead"  runat="server" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this)" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chksub"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

After that write the Java script function **SelectAllCheckboxes**

```
// select all check boxes

function SelectAllCheckboxes(spanChk) {
    // Added as ASPX uses SPAN for checkbox
    var oItem = spanChk.children;
    var theBox = (spanChk.type == "checkbox") ?
        spanChk : spanChk.children.item[0];
    xState = theBox.checked;
    elm = theBox.form.elements;
    for (i = 0; i < elm.length; i++)
        if (elm[i].type == "checkbox" && elm[i].id != theBox.id) {
            //elm[i].click();
            if (!elm[i].disabled) {
                if (elm[i].checked != xState)
                    elm[i].click();
            }
            //elm[i].checked=xState;
        }
    }
```

After write the .cs page load event first bind the grid view and **chheader.checked=true;**